# from c to assembly language with AT&T Syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, getchar

I wrote a very simple C program that prints a character to standard output

```
#include <stdio.h>


int c;

int main(){


 while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) {

putchar(c);

}

return 0;
}
```

then I used `gcc -S -m32 -fno-pic -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables lauf.c` to covert it to assembly language and got this

```
.file   "lauf.c"
.comm   c,4,4                 // global variable c with 4 bytes .. 
                               The second 4 means alignment
                               but what exactly does it mean? 
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function

main:
leal    4(%esp), %ecx  
andl    $-16, %esp
pushl   -4(%ecx)
pushl   %ebp                   // start of stack frame
movl    %esp, %ebp             // gives stackpointer the value of the 
                                   basepointer
pushl   %ecx
subl    $4, %esp                   //end of stackframe
jmp .L2

.L3:
movl    c, %eax
subl    $12, %esp    // why does the compiler subtract 12 from esp?
pushl   %eax
call    putchar
addl    $16, %esp    // why esp +16?

.L2:
call    getchar    // calls getchar but where is c assigned to getchar?
movl    %eax, c    
movl    c, %eax    
cmpl    $-1, %eax   
jne .L3                     
movl    $0, %eax
movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
leave
leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
ret
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1) 4.9.4"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I added some questions in the assembly file.
Could someone explain what exactly is going on in the assembly file?

Comment: Looks like the system requires that the stack be 16-byte multiple aligned. Since the `putchar` argument, `c`, is 4 bytes, 12 more bytes are needed to pad the stack pointer before the call. Thus the `subl $12, %esp`. The `addl $16, %esp` after the call cleans up the stack to get it back to where it was: 16 comes from 4 + 12 to undo pushing `c` and reserving the 12 byte pad. The `getchar` call returns result in `eax`. That should be obvious from the `movl %eax, c` that follows. The "alignement" in the `.comm   c,4,4` means means `c` must be aligned on a multiple of 4 byte address.

Comment: The i386 System V ABI requires that ESP is 16-byte aligned before a `call` instruction, so one 4-byte arg needs 12 bytes of padding.  And popping them all off the stack needs +16.  With optimization enabled, gcc wouldn't do that inside the loop.  Or apparently it would: https://godbolt.org/g/MtTC4Q.  That's unfortunate.  (And BTW, you don't need to make your loop counter a global.  You can use `-fverbose-asm` to have `gcc -S` annotate the asm.)

Comment: You seem to be compiling without optimizations turned on.  Without optimizations, the compiler often generates fairly nonsensical code and inspecting its output is of little use, not even as an educational exercise.

Comment: *where is c assigned to getchar?*  In the very next instruction, `movl    %eax, c` stores the return value from EAX into the static storage for `c`.

Comment: @lurker thanks so that means if eax = EOF which is -1 it would be -1 - -1 which is -1+1= 0 ? then the jne wouldn't be executed

Comment: @fuz my university professor wants us to compile it like that

Comment: @momonosuke `cmpl    $-1, %eax` is comparing the return of `c = getchar()` with `-1`. Implicitly, `cmpl` does subtract the value of `%eax` from `-1` and `jne` will jump if it's not a zero result.

Comment: When posting code, select the code and click the `{}` widget, which will shift it right 4 spaces (and cause it to be rendered as code).  Check alignment in the preview, below the post edit window.

Comment: @fuz: with optimization, it can seem even less meaningful, especially if it's a longer bit of code.  I've spent decades debugging C code using disassembly in embedded systems.  I find that unoptimized code is usually the best code to look at first.  But yeah, the compiler doesn't write it the way we would ourselves (with or withoug optimization).  To learn why, just write a compiler. ;-)

Comment: @JeffLearman: `gcc -O3`'s choices are sometimes at least close to how I'd write something.  `gcc -O0` *never* is.  `gcc -O1` or `-Og` is maybe reasonable for a beginner to look at: don't spill everything to memory between every statement, but without a lot of the more aggressive optimizations.  Choosing optimization level to look at very much depends on what you want to know about the asm.  If you just want to see how the ABI works, write functions that call other functions and compile at -O3 to leave out as much stuff that's *not* necessary for a function call as possible.